# Taking about something that happend in the past

Tags: grammar

I was wonder if you tell me your opinion about below statement specially tense
"I can have special time for practicing what I had learn before"

Answer (score 1):

There are two tenses involved in this sentence

> I can have special time.

This is in the simple present tense.

> I had **learnt** before.

Is in the past perfect tense

**what** is used as a relative pronoun.

Comment: thanks. Is it common in Speaking or Writing?